# Cómo resuelvo este problema al migrar un proyecto Django?

Tags: python, django

Cómo resuelvo este problema al migrar un proyecto Django?, (`python manage.py migrate`)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> C:\Django>python manage.py migrate                                                                                                                                                                                 Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                                                                   File "C:\Users\diego\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 243, in create                                                                                            app_module = import_module(app_name)                                                                                                                                                                             File "C:\Users\diego\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\importlib_*init*_.py", line 127, in import_module                                                                                                   return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)                                                                                                                                                      File "", line 1030, in *gcd_import                                                                                                                                                    File "", line 1007, in *find_and_load                                                                                                                                                 File "", line 984, in *find_and_load_unlocked                                                                                                                                       ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'GestionClientes'                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                                                                   File "C:\Django\manage.py", line 22, in                                                                                                                                                                      main()                                                                                                                                                                                                           File "C:\Django\manage.py", line 18, in main                                                                                                                                                                         execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)                                                                                                                                                                              File "C:\Users\diego\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management_*init**.py", line 425, in execute_from_command_line                                                            utility.execute()                                                                                                                                                                                                File "C:\Users\diego\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management_*init**.py", line 401, in execute                                                                              django.setup()                                                                                                                                                                                                   File "C:\Users\diego\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django_*init**.py", line 24, in setup                                                                                                 apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)                                                                                                                                                                           File "C:\Users\diego\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 91, in populate                                                                                         app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)                                                                                                                                                                             File "C:\Users\diego\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 245, in create                                                                                            raise ImproperlyConfigured(                                                                                                                                                                                    django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Cannot import 'GestionClientes'. Check that 'Django.apps.GestionClientes.apps.GestionclientesConfig.name' is correct.

Comment: has leído el error?

Comment: Puedes mostarnos el codigo que llevas hecho hasya el momento?

Answer (score 0):

Tienes q entrar al archivo
apps.py de la app GestionClientes y modificar el parámetro name. Por lo q veo la app se llama Gestionclientes y no GestionClientes, tienes q verificar también q esté bien puesto en las installer_apps en el setting

Comment: gracias por responder, lastimosamente el error persiste, incluso he creado otro proyecto y me sigue saltando el mismo error, el path está bien colocado, ya había hecho varios proyectos y núnca tuve ese problema, incluso queriendo correr mis programas antiguos ahora me salta el mismo error

Answer (score 0):

probando y probando, resulto que la solución es agregar un ".apps" al final de la app, esto se debe a la nueva actualización de django:

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # --------------------------
    'Django.Apps.GestionClientes.apps',
]
```